# Давайте разделим [merge] на [git-merge] и [sql-merge]?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение, метки

Есть метка [merge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge). Но там каша из различных тем. Может быть их стоит разнести на [git-merge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge), [sql-merge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-merge) и т.п. Часть вопросов на отвлечённые темы.

---

Кажется, что, в целом, было бы круто мелкие метки подмёрджить в более крупные.

---

Начал объединять и понял, что [merge](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) -- очень разная история. Есть про [pandas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas), есть про [sql](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), [git](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) и [алгоритм](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc). Кажется, что можно сделать тематическое моделирование и избавиться от совсем мелких категорий. Здесь вопрос к администрации. Возможно ли это как-то автоматизировать будет? Например, я могу со своего аккаунта скриптом ходить? Можно ли для него капчу будет вырубить?

Comment: Кто предложил, тому и разделять :)

Comment: стоит написать рекомендацию класть вопросы по git в метку git-merge

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я не против. Если научите как делать

Comment: Как делать? Ну как обычно вопрос редактируется. Только метки изменить на подходящие. Или о чём речь?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ как смёрджить сами метки, чтобы ими люди не пользовались. И потом удалить.

Comment: Смёржить? Их же наоборот надо разделить! Удаление метки не решит проблему, если её специально не внести в список запрещённых (никто этого делать не будет).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ хочется подмёрджить одну метку к дургой. Т.е. выпиливаем из всех впоросов упоминание метки. А прицпеляем одну метку к другой

Comment: [9 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git+merge) можно и руками. UPD: перебросил